# Build package with system_lib not found

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

```
 I run catkin_make to build my package with this Warning:



-- +++ processing catkin package: 'katrina_gui'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(katrina_gui)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'system_lib' but neither
  'system_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor 'system_lib_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  katrina_gui/CMakeLists.txt:22 (catkin_package)
```

My Environment Is:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 
ROS-Kinetic
```

I run this package under ROS-Indigo before, how can i fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288967/build-package-with-system_lib-not-found/) by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`system_lib` is the name used as an example in the template `CMakeLists.txt` that `catkin_create_pkg` generates for you.

It is not intended to be an actual package.

Unless you happen to have a system dependency actually called `system_lib`, I recommend you remove it from your `catkin_package(.. DEPENDS ..)` list.

> I run this package under ROS-Indigo before

I can't be sure, but I'm going to assume that would be impossible. Both Indigo and Kinetic use the same versions of Catkin, so I'd expect the same error to be shown to you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-04-18**:
Thanks, I'll try it later